# Can Metro style C++ apps be compiled using the MBCS

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can Metro style C++ apps for Windows 8 be compiled using the MBCS as opposed to UNICODE.  In Visual Studio 2012, the option to choose the 'Character Set' does not seem to be available for Metro Style apps and 'UNICODE' is defined by default. Are we forced to use UTF16 strings?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. As `char` is defined to be 16-bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forced to use UTF16 strings - the WinRT string datatype is unicode, so every string that interacts with winrt APIs needs to be unicode.

You're free to write your app using whatever character sets you want, but you'll need to convert to UTF16 before you call any winrt APIs.